# Buscar y reemplazar valores en un string en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un texto de entrada como este `(;ALTO;*;ANCHO;);*;VALOR;`, este texto puede variar a múltiples formas, por ejemplo `((((;ANCHO;+;ALTO;)/;FUELLE;)+;MANIJA;)*;VALOR;)/2`

Mi objetivo es poder reemplazar todas las palabras por su valor correspondiente definido en variables, para el primer ejemplo `(50*40)*15.2` o para el segundo ejemplo algo como esto `((((40+50)/10)+22.5)*15.2)/2`, tengo este codigo pero no hace lo que requiero.

Alguien puede darme alguna idea de que le falta a mi código?

Codigo Java

```
String ANCHO = "40";
String ALTO = "50";
String FUELLE = "10";
String MANIJA = "22.5";
String VALOR = "15.2";

String[] arregloPalabrasFormula = new String[]{"ANCHO", "ALTO", "FUELLE", "MANIJA", "VALOR"};
String input = "(;ALTO;*;ANCHO;);*;VALOR;";
String withoutSign = input.replaceAll(";", "");
String finalString = "";
String partialString= "";
boolean found = false;


for (int i = 0; i < arregloPalabrasFormula.length; i++) {

    if (withoutSign.contains(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
        found = true;

        if (found){
            finalString += partialString;
            System.out.println("FOUND AND IS...."+ arregloPalabrasFormula[i]);
            if (arregloPalabrasFormula[i].equals(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
                partialString = withoutSign.replace(arregloPalabrasFormula[i], ALTO);
            }else if (arregloPalabrasFormula[i].equals(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
                partialString = withoutSign.replace(arregloPalabrasFormula[i], ANCHO);
            }else if (arregloPalabrasFormula[i].equals(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
                partialString = withoutSign.replace(arregloPalabrasFormula[i], FUELLE);
            }else if (arregloPalabrasFormula[i].equals(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
                partialString = withoutSign.replace(arregloPalabrasFormula[i], MANIJA);
            }else if (arregloPalabrasFormula[i].equals(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
                partialString = withoutSign.replace(arregloPalabrasFormula[i], VALOR);
            }
        }
    }
    finalString = partialString;
}

System.out.println("FINAL STRING..." + finalString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizar un mapa es una buena opción en este  caso:

```
String[] arregloPalabrasFormula = new String[]{"ANCHO", "ALTO", "FUELLE", "MANIJA", "VALOR"};
String input = "(;ALTO;*;ANCHO;);*;VALOR;";
String withoutSign = input.replaceAll(";", "");
boolean found = false;          
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ANCHO", 40D);
map.put("ALTO", 50D);
map.put("FUELLE", 10D);
map.put("MANIJA", 22.5D);
map.put("VALOR", 15.2D);

for (int i = 0; i < arregloPalabrasFormula.length; i++) {
    if (withoutSign.contains(arregloPalabrasFormula[i])) {
        found = true;
        if (found){
            withoutSign = withoutSign.replace(arregloPalabrasFormula[i], map.get(arregloPalabrasFormula[i]).toString());
            System.out.println(withoutSign);

        }
    }
}

System.out.println("FINAL STRING..." + withoutSign);
```

Comment: Tienes mucha razon!!

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que  tu texto de entrada es:

```
 String texto= "(;ALTO;*;ANCHO;);*;VALOR;"
```

para quitar las ; seria:

```
String withoutSign = texto.replaceAll(";", "");
```

De igual forma para los:

```
  String texto2 = withoutSign.replaceAll("ALTO",ALTO)
```

Comment: es correcto lo que dices, ya elimino los ; , pero el string puede variar, por ejemplo  a esto `((((;ANCHO;+;ALTO;)/;FUELLE;)+;MANIJA;)*;VALOR;)/2` o a esto `((((;FUELLE;*;ALTO;)/;ANCHO;)+;VALOR;)*;MANIJA;)/2` necesito reemplazar todas las palabras que estén en el string de entrada dinámicamente, te agradezco me digas si no soy muy claro. Gracias